# How to pass creativeId into CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert() method using Google CM360 API

Tags: javascript, double-click-advertising, google-apps-script-api

I'm using Google Apps Script and using the DoubleClickCampaigns services v3.5, which allows me to use CM360 APIs v3.5

I'm trying to associate a creative to a campaign using [campaignCreativeAssociations.insert()](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/campaignCreativeAssociations/insert)

```
  const profileId = '1234' //fake
  const campaignId = '12345'
  const creativeId = '5551234'
  DoubleClickCampaigns.CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert(profileId,campaignId,creativeId);
```

The above returns this error

```
 GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to dfareporting.campaignCreativeAssociations.insert failed with error: 8058 : Creative ID required.
```

Using the "Try this method" on the side bar of the documentation site has a sample code shows that I should instead pass in an object into the .insert parameter

```
 {"profileId":###,"campaignId",###,resource:{"creativeId":###}}
```

Testing the code by running it on the documentation website (it works on live data) I can confirm that the creative was associated to the campaign.

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.dfareporting.campaignCreativeAssociations.insert({
      "profileId": 123,
      "campaignId": 456,
      "resource": {
        "creativeId": 123,
      }
    })
```

However when I try to rebuild the same code into my Apps Script environment, I get this error

```
DoubleClickCampaigns.CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert({
  "profileId": 123,
  "campaignId": 555,
  "resource": {
    "creativeId": 555123,
  }
})



Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only
```

Is the issue with the parameter? Following the sample code gives me an error regarding passing the wrong number of parameters. What should my code me so that I can use Apps Script to insert creatives into a CM360 campaign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the arguments of `DoubleClickCampaigns.CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert()` are as follows.

```
insert(resource: Dfareporting_v3_5.Dfareporting.V3_5.Schema.CampaignCreativeAssociation, profileId: string, campaignId: string)
```

When this is reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var resource = { "creativeId": 555123 };
var profileId = "123";
var campaignId = "555"
DoubleClickCampaigns.CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert(resource, profileId, campaignId);
```

- It seems that the values of `profileId` and `campaignId` are the string type.

#### Reference:

- [Method: campaignCreativeAssociations.insert](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.5/campaignCreativeAssociations/insert)

Comment: Thank you! I've marked this as the correct answer. For further reference as I work more with APIs, how were you able to pull the arguments like the one you quoted above? Was it listed in the documentation?

Comment: @kevhol Thank you for replying. In this case, I checked the arguments by the autocompletion of the script editor. For example, under enabling DoubleClickCampaigns API, when `DoubleClickCampaigns.CampaignCreativeAssociations.insert(` is inputted to the script editor, you can see the information in the opened dialog on the script editor.